# Parsing a JSON to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, graphql

I'm pretty new to JSON syntax, I mainly work in python for GIS purposes.  I'm trying to take the results of a GraphQL query and parse them into a Pandas Dataframe, so that I can use those figures to update a different file.  I've been hitting my head against the wall for two days trying to find a way to read this result, can anyone here steer me in the right direction?  I just want to pull the name of the sensor, the timeUTC field, and the final Value into a table of some kind.

Here's a sample result of the graphQL query  (secure data blanked):

```
{
  "data": {
    "securityToken": "***********************************",
    "node": {
      "name": "*****************",
      "locations": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "VW_01",
              "lastSampleForAllSensorTypes": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:02.128000Z",
                      "finalValue": 3.6
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:00.069000Z",
                      "finalValue": 16.59
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-08T18:30:02.082000Z",
                      "finalValue": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Tilt_01",
              "lastSampleForAllSensorTypes": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z",
                      "finalValue": 1.5515986838415172
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z",
                      "finalValue": -0.04759077784648378
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2022-08-23T08:30:09.098000Z",
                      "finalValue": 48302.57888302765
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.308000Z",
                      "finalValue": 3.593
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:00.144000Z",
                      "finalValue": 18.97
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T03:30:09.209000Z",
                      "finalValue": 0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z",
                      "finalValue": 0.08889998474121086
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z",
                      "finalValue": -0.003600174713134674
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "timeUTC": "2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z",
                      "finalValue": 88.5111
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using this right now, it obviously doesn't work, but am I even close?  Haha

```
url = '*************************************'
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)

data = json.loads(r.text)


df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['name', 'timeUTC', 'finalValue'])
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument to `.json_normalize()` is the `record_path` i.e. the list of records.

In this case you can use `data.node.locations.edges.node.lastSampleForAllSensorTypes.edges`

```
pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=["data", "node", "locations", "edges", "node", "lastSampleForAllSensorTypes", "edges"],
)
```

```
                   node.timeUTC  node.finalValue
0   2023-02-09T16:30:02.128000Z         3.600000
1   2023-02-09T16:30:00.069000Z        16.590000
2   2023-02-08T18:30:02.082000Z         0.000000
3   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z         1.551599
4   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        -0.047591
5   2022-08-23T08:30:09.098000Z     48302.578883
6   2023-02-09T16:30:09.308000Z         3.593000
7   2023-02-09T16:30:00.144000Z        18.970000
8   2023-02-09T03:30:09.209000Z         0.000000
9   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z         0.088900
10  2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        -0.003600
11  2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        88.511100
```

You can then use `meta=` to bring in the `name` values.

```
pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=["data", "node", "locations", "edges", "node", "lastSampleForAllSensorTypes", "edges"],
    meta=[["data", "node", "locations", "edges", "node", "name"]],
)
```

```
                   node.timeUTC  node.finalValue data.node.locations.edges.node.name
0   2023-02-09T16:30:02.128000Z         3.600000                               VW_01
1   2023-02-09T16:30:00.069000Z        16.590000                               VW_01
2   2023-02-08T18:30:02.082000Z         0.000000                               VW_01
3   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z         1.551599                             Tilt_01
4   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        -0.047591                             Tilt_01
5   2022-08-23T08:30:09.098000Z     48302.578883                             Tilt_01
6   2023-02-09T16:30:09.308000Z         3.593000                             Tilt_01
7   2023-02-09T16:30:00.144000Z        18.970000                             Tilt_01
8   2023-02-09T03:30:09.209000Z         0.000000                             Tilt_01
9   2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z         0.088900                             Tilt_01
10  2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        -0.003600                             Tilt_01
11  2023-02-09T16:30:09.202000Z        88.511100                             Tilt_01
```